# FFmpeg: Issues muxing/copying ASS subtitle streams from one MKV source with another MKV, causes 33secs of missing subtitle at the beginning

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, matroska, copy

Hey first time posting,

But I really tried to look all around for a solution, even tried a couple of options that worked for me before for a similar issue with WebVTT from another solution [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000319/ffmpeg-doesnt-detect-the-subtitle-format-webvtt-and-refuses-to-copy-it)].

Anyways, I have two sources, first MKV I only want the ASS subtitles it has (and all the relevant attachments for it) and the second MKV I want to keep everything in it as is. So I just want to mux/copy the ASS subtitles from the first with that of the second MKV.

I initially tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i "first.mkv" -i "second.mkv" -map 1 -map 0:s -map 0:t -map_metadata 0 -c copy "output.mkv"
```

When reviewing this, I noticed that the output resulted in a working file, but the first 33seconds of the ASS subtitles dont work or appear. However, during the rest of the video they work fine and are actually synced well.

I then tried doing something similar to when I encountered something similar with WebVTT subtitles, even went overkill on it:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100000000M -probesize 100000000M -c:s ass -i "first.mkv" -i "second.mkv" -map 1 -map 0 -map -0:a -map -0:v -map 0:t -map_metadata 0 -c copy "output.mkv"
```

I even tried the above command without forcing the decoder. I even tried doing variations more like this:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100000000M -probesize 100000000M -c:s ass -i "first.mkv" -i "second.mkv" -map 1 -map 0 -map -0:a -map -0:v -map 0:t -map_metadata 0 -c copy "output.mkv"
```

There isnt any warnings or errors that popup, and even the attachments copy over correctly and the subtitles for the portion of video that works look good and correct.

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

**UPDATE 1 (Jun 24, 2021)**

Output of `ffmpeg -i "first.mkv"` for inspection of file if helpful

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'first.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : S01E01
    encoder         : libebml v1.4.2 + libmatroska v1.6.4
    creation_time   : 2021-06-19T15:23:43.000000Z
  Duration: 00:23:37.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1859 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 60.978000
      Metadata:
        title           : Intro
    Chapter #0:1: start 60.978000, end 827.326000
      Metadata:
        title           : Part A
    Chapter #0:2: start 827.326000, end 1417.120000
      Metadata:
        title           : Part B
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : first
      BPS             : 1527506
      DURATION        : 00:23:36.999000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 33974
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 270559312
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v57.0.0 ('Till The End') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2021-06-19 15:23:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 128000
      DURATION        : 00:23:37.120000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 44285
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 22673920
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v57.0.0 ('Till The End') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2021-06-19 15:23:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:2(jpn): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 128000
      DURATION        : 00:23:37.120000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 44285
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 22673920
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v57.0.0 ('Till The End') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2021-06-19 15:23:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Signs & Songs
      BPS             : 4446
      DURATION        : 00:19:35.720000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 2858
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 653546
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v57.0.0 ('Till The End') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2021-06-19 15:23:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : Dialogue
      BPS             : 3881
      DURATION        : 00:23:26.400000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 3320
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 682307
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v57.0.0 ('Till The End') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2021-06-19 15:23:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:5: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 400x567 [SAR 350:350 DAR 400:567], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
  Stream #0:6: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Amaranth-Bold.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:7: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Amaranth-BoldItalic.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:8: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Amaranth-Italic.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:9: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Amaranth-Regular.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:10: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : ARIALNB.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:11: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : COMFORTAA-LIGHT.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:12: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Comfortaa-VariableFont_wght.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:13: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : DerNeueSpargel-Vwzx.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:14: Attachment: otf
    Metadata:
      filename        : FOT-ModeMinALargeStd-B.otf
      mimetype        : application/vnd.ms-opentype
  Stream #0:15: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : GalapagosDemo-WyPYY.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:16: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : keifont.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:17: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Koowalsky.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:18: Attachment: otf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Lalezar-Regular.otf
      mimetype        : application/vnd.ms-opentype
  Stream #0:19: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Moire-Regular.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:20: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : olivia.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:21: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : RobotRenegades-LxGE.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:22: Attachment: otf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Saira-Medium.otf
      mimetype        : application/vnd.ms-opentype
  Stream #0:23: Attachment: otf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Sedexpersonaluse-y5jq.otf
      mimetype        : application/vnd.ms-opentype
  Stream #0:24: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : seguisym.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:25: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : sylfaen.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:26: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Vogue  Bold.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `-fix_sub_duration` option before the inputs, documented as:

"Fix subtitles durations. For each subtitle, wait for the next packet in the same stream and adjust the duration of the first to avoid overlap. This is necessary with some subtitles codecs, especially DVB subtitles, because the duration in the original packet is only a rough estimate and the end is actually marked by an empty subtitle frame. Failing to use this option when necessary can result in exaggerated durations or muxing failures due to non-monotonic timestamps.

Note that this option will delay the output of all data until the next subtitle packet is decoded: it may increase memory consumption and latency a lot.
"

From your first example:

```sh
ffmpeg -fix_sub_duration -i "first.mkv" -i "second.mkv" -map 1 -map 0:s -map 0:t -map_metadata 0 -c copy "output.mkv"
```

And report back.

Comment: Thanks for the informative response, wasnt familiar with the command so I appreciate you taking the time to help me learn.

I tried it, with a few variations again, but it didnt seem to remedy that 33seconds of missing ASS subs at the beginning.

Thought to update the question and add the FFmpeg info output to the first source being inputted with no output, incase that helps diagnose it further or anything.